# Sidenav throwing exception: Error during evaluation of "onShown"

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I use this sidenav

```
<div layout="column" style="height:60px;">
<md-sidenav-container layout="row" flex>
<md-content flex layout-padding>
  <div layout="column" layout-fill layout-align="top right" style="width: 50px; position: absolute;
top: -8px;
right: 55px;
font-size: 18px;">
    <button md-raised-button (click)="open('right')" [hidden]="rightOpened" class="md-primary">
      Filtros
    </button>
  </div>
  <div flex></div>
</md-content>
<md-sidenav name="right" align="right" layout="column" (onShown)="input.focus()">
  <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
    <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
  </md-toolbar>
```

After this I call different components. I just learned how to use developer tool to see errors and warnings, so I'm quite the newby, but I don't recall it throwing long ago, before I implemented a lot of changes.

The problem is I don't quite understand the error well enough:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "onShown"
```

...

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
```

...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_SidenavBasicUsage_0.handleEventInternal (viewFactory_SidenavBasicUsage:361:24)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent
```

Since I don't see anywhere where does that relate to my code. I got it done, as to speak, I believe from materializecss, and now I wonder if keep on ignoring the error, since it works just fine, or do something about it (I'd rather do it but I don't know where to start poking it so I can fix it).

Comment: Where do you declare `input` variable?

Comment: ... or what is `input` supposed to refer to?

Comment: I did not, as it was explained in the answer below, it was an example and as such it expected me to properly define anything that was necessary. I completely failed to understand that, I couldn't quite see it. Thanks for the help once again, it may seem trivial but I spend way too many hours looking up this stuff

Comment: I get that @Pace , that's why I try to appreciate as much as I can the help offered :( . It's not simply a matter of I looked up a bit, then asked here. Maaany things I either get an answer here, or goes unsolved/does not get a solution. I am trying to put as much effort into the question itself as I can, for example. I feel I'm doing ok-ish now that I often get an answer, vs the times I rarely got one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the comments, there is a snippet of your HTML:

```
<md-sidenav name="right" align="right" layout="column" (onShown)="input.focus()">
```

The issue is with `(onShown)="input.focus()"`.  This code may have come from some kind of example.  Typically the intent of this type of focus-on-show is to focus on an element inside of the sidenav when the sidenav becomes visible.  This is often done for both ease of use for keyboard users and for accessibility reasons (a visually impaired person might not otherwise know the sidenav just appeared).

However, the problem is likely that you don't have any variable named `input`.  If you meant to have a variable named `input` and expected it to focus then there are a few different ways that could have been done and we don't have enough code to tell what you were trying to do.  A common example might look like...

```
<md-sidenav name="right" align="right" layout="column" (onShown)="input.focus()">
  <input #input type="text" class="search"/>
</md-sidenav>
```

Note the `#input` is declaring a template reference variable named input which can be referred to elsewhere in the template (e.g. `input.focus()`).

Comment: You are completely right, I did not have any such variable. In fact I believe I do not need it, and when I removed  (onShown)="input.focus()" the error was gone and the rest of the code keeps working fine, so, it was a problem of not knowing what the code does. Thanks for taking the time, it does help me a great lot